# Is this C++ Guessing Game syntactically correct?

Tags: c++, random

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

int main(){
int min = 1;
int max = 100;
int count = 0;
int randomint = min + (rand() % (int)(max - min + 1));
bool isCorrect = true;
while(!isCorrect){
    int guess = 0;
    cout << "What is your guess? " << endl;
    cin >> guess;
    if(guess < randomint){
        cout << "Too low!" << endl;
        count++;
    } else if (guess > randomint){
        cout << "Too high!" << endl;
        count++;
    } else{
        cout << "Correct!" << endl;
        cout << "Number of Guesses: " << count << endl;
        isCorrect = true;
    }
}
}
```

New C++ Programming.  I couldn't get this to compile one IDEOne because it doesn't have the input system I need to work this program.  I have to submit this for a class shortly, but given that my larger disk (where all my software was stored) was corrupted last night.
I apologize for the silliness of this question.

Comment: It's syntactically correct, not logically. Your loop will never run.

Comment: IDEOne compiles it just fine.

Comment: The code will run, but will never allow you to guess anything before it stops execution due to your while loop parameter being false at the start of the game

Comment: @Smac89 - This is not true. I guessed before it stops execution that the while loop is a noop.

Comment: @EdHeal, Are you saying that the above code actually went into the while loop when you executed it? Can you prove this? Here is me running it on [ideone](http://ideone.com/v2SEEh) with no input and it prints success

Comment: Yes - It hit `while(!isCorrect){` - the start of the loop. The computer say **NO** - Guess it is how you define "into"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is **syntactically** correct, but **not logically**, due to

```
bool isCorrect = true;
```

which prevents loop from starting, it should be

```
bool isCorrect = false;
```

and works like a charm (but it would be reasonable to initialize the random number generator by for example running `srand(time(NULL));`)

Comment: I'm sorry, guys.  I had a blonde moment.
Thank you.
Smac89, thank you as well, sir.
Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

There are two things logically wrong in your program:

1. The game won't run at all, since `isCorrect` is initially true.
2. The random number generator doesn't get a seed, so `rand()` will return the same value on every run and `randomint` is always the same. You should call [`srand( seed )`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/srand) beforehand, where `seed` is a unsigned (for example `time(0)`).*

<sup>*actually, your game will still run if you don't do this, but it's easy to beat after the first try</sup>